What happens when Kafka topic retention time is greater than log.roll time?
I want to change the retention time only for one Kafka topic. I am curious as to how deletion is handled if the retention time is set to be greater than the log.roll.ms setting of the broker. I use AKHQ as a GUI. Will this data still be searchable through it?
In my current set up, my topic retention times are less than the log roll time. The records are still searchable until the log is rolled even though the retention time has lapsed but I am curious what happens in the inverse situation.

Retention time only applies to closed (rolled) log segments.
So, if the retention is longer, it'll just delete older log files than that roll-time.

Does that mean the data is still searchable even though the log is rolled?

That's correct, unless you set auto.offset.reset=latest and have low consumer lag
